# IntelliJ and facets

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea

I recently switched to IntelliJ IDEA 11 and after what I understand facets is a way to configure frameworks etc. It also downloads the needed libraries.

When you add the EJB facet to a project you get a folder inside the EJB module named `lib` and it contains jars. What is these libraries used for? Compilation or? And does these libraries exist in the artifact?

Comment: If I recall it well, when you start with Maven (you are talking about artifacts so let me guess you use it), the lib directory is created only when you miss the right dependencies in you pom files.

Answer (score 1):

What scope a lib has can be seen in the project settings *modules/Dependencies* wehre certain libs are connected to your project with a certain scope (provided, compile, test, runtime).

Whether or not the jar will be included in your artifact automatically, I'm not sure. Therefor best have a look at the project settings *artifacts/YOUR_ARTIFACT/output_layout* where your artifact is assabled. Look for warnings (lib missing or kinda stuff) then click through your artifact and search the folder *WEB-INF/lib* and its contents.

hth